# How to find parent element by selector in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I want to find parent element having css class ".site-map-section` of current node. Can someone help me how to achieve this?

Sample :

```
require(["dojo/dom-prop", "dojo/query", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/NodeList-dom"], function (domProp, query, dom, on) {
        query('.footer .site-map a').forEach(function (node) {
                   var parentCategory = query(node).parent('.site-map-section');
           console.log(parentCategory);         

        });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use method `closest` provided by `dojo/NodeList-traverse`.

```
require(["dojo/dom-prop", "dojo/query", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/NodeList-dom", "dojo/NodeList-traverse"], function (domProp, query, dom, on) {
    query('.footer .site-map a').forEach(function (node) {
               var parentCategory = query(node).closest('.site-map-section');
       console.log(parentCategory);         

    });
```

});

For more details, see:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/NodeList-traverse.html#closest

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the following.

```
// Assuming there is only one element of class site-map-section
var parentCategory = query('.site-map-section',node)[0].parentNode;
```

if you want to use the parent() function than you need to require `dojo/NodeList-traverse`. You code will than be

```
var parentCategory = query('.site-map-section',node).parent();
```

Comment: Note that the requirement is "parent element having css class `.site-map-section`". So `.parent()` is not enough

Comment: I am not interested in immediate parent. I want the parent in the hierarchy having class name "site-map-section".